# Call a python code from WCF

Tags: python-2.7, wcf

I need to make a python code available as WCF for another application to access it. The python code was build by the data science team and have no ability to change it. I tried running the program as a process shell but it gives 'System.InvalidOperationException' exception.
I created the same program as C# console application and it works fine. The question is
a. Is this the right way to go about making python code available to another application (REST API is not an option).
b. What is the issue with my code.

```
public string ClassifyText(string value)
{
    string textoutput = "";

    string exeFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/python.exe");
    string argName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/predictionscript.py");

    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = exeFileName;
    start.Arguments = argName;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            textoutput = result;
        }
    }
    return textoutput;
}
```